# Customizing Output When Referring to List of Symbols

Tags: cross-referencing

For my thesis, I am making a List of Symbols, which looks currently like this.

```
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}


\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Metric}]{metric}{\ensuremath{g_{\mu\nu}}}
```

As you can see, I am using indices. What I want (and don't know how to achieve) is to refer to an element in the list of symbols when the indices are on a different height than given in the list of symbols. For instance, `metric` is in the list of symbols defined with lower indices but how can I use `\gls{metric}` such that it prints it with upper indices? Additionally, sometimes, I want to refer to an element of the list of symbols where I want the output to be the boldsymbol of that element. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!